# create folder based on patial file name, and move specific files into specific folder

Tags: string, shell

I have thousands of files need to move into different folders. File names are:
a_b_c001_1_aug_03_08.09.41.34.tif
a_b_c001_1_aug_03_08.29.16.33.tif
a_b_c002_1_aug_03_08.59.31.21.tif
a_b_c002_1_aug_03_07.19.51.33.tif
a_b_c002_1_aug_03_07.55.11.54.tif
......
a_b_c163_1_aug_03_08.09.11.34.tif

I want to create folders c001, c002, ..., c163, and move a_b_c001_1_aug_03_08.09.41.34.tif
a_b_c001_1_aug_03_08.29.16.33.tif into folder c001, move a_b_c002_1_aug_03_08.59.31.21.tif
a_b_c002_1_aug_03_07.19.51.33.tif into folder c002, move a_b_c163_1_aug_03_08.09.11.34.tif into folder c163.

Could anyone help me figure out how to write a script for this? I have little knowledge about coding, I know I might need to use for loop, however, this task is too hard for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I worked this after several trials. for anyone who wants to solve this problem, my script is this : for i in a_b_????_*.tif ; do folder=${i:4:4}; mkdir $folder; num=${i:5:3} ln -s "$i" c"$num"/ done –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bash way of doing it, if all your file names have the same form and have only 3 digits:

```
for i in *.tif; do folder=${i:4:4}; mkdir -p $folder; cp $i $folder;done
```

if you have more than 3 digits after the c you can try this way:

```
for i in *.tif; do
  folder=${i:4}
  under="_"
  rest=${folder#*$under}
  folder=${folder:: $(( ${#folder} - ${#rest} - ${#under} ))}
  mkdir -p $folder
  cp $i $folder
done
```

If your prefix is not always a_b_ or something equivalent it will not work. But you can improve it.

Comment: I also need the specific file to specific folder, not all into one folder. Could you please help me figure out this?

Comment: Thanks, now it works out! And for anyone who wants to solve this problem, my script is this : for i in a_b_????_*.tif ; do
    folder=${i:4:4};
    mkdir $folder;
    num=${i:5:3}
    ln -s "$i" c"$num"/
done

Comment: you should add -p with mkdir to avoid error since folders are created without cheking if they exist before. I dont understand why you need num. if you want create links instead of copying you can do:
a_b_????_*.tif ; do folder=${i:4:4}; mkdir -p $folder;  ln -s "$i" "$folder";done